# How can I append some html inside <td> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a `<hr>` element into a `<td>` in jquery based on the class. I've managed to find the `<td>` elements I want to append without a problem, but I can't add the html - the `<td>` already contains some html, I want to append this on the end.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var something = "something";
    var element = $('td').filter(':contains(something)').html('<p>Hello</p>');
            console.log(element);
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share markup as well?

Comment: Then use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: filter(':contains(something)') would be filter(':contains('+something+')')

Comment: My filter wasn't working properly @Roy this was the fix thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using .html() you can use .append() which just added whatever you write into the end of the div.

Like this

```
$('td').filter(':contains(something)').append('<p>Hello</p>')
```

This will put hello after filtered `<td>`

You can also use .prepend() to add things to the begining of the div.

Comment: I'm trying to add something into a <td> rather than a <div>. append() doesn't seem to be working for me!

Comment: Ah, my filter wasn't working properly... I'll see myself out

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this: https://jsfiddle.net/jo2t5yL0/1/
It's working with `<td>` and `.html()`
Maybe you forget to include jquery lib?

Answer (score 0):

try appending..something like this... and make sure you're using the jquery library

```
var element =$('td').filter(':contains(something)').append('<p>Hello</p>');
```